# no authentication for incoming mail on sendmail, linux (debian)

Tags: linux, email, hosting, sendmail

I have installed sendmail on my webserver. Sending and receiving emails does work, but when I use authentication on port 25 ( to avoid spam attacks), I can't receive emails anymore.
All I get is an authentication error.

Is there a way to deactivate authentication in sendmail for incoming mail?

**Edit 1** : In my sendmail configuration I have this lines:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(Name=ESMTP,Port=465,Modifiers=a')
DAEMON_OPTIONS(Name=STARTTLS,Port=587,Modifiers=a') 
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=SMTP,Modifiers=a')
```

Comment: What **exactly** means "when I use authentication on port 25"? [I have seen incredible number of misconfigurations ]

Comment: in my sendmail configuration I have this lines: DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=ESMTP,Port=465,Modifiers=a')  
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=STARTTLS,Port=587,Modifiers=a')  
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=SMTP,Modifiers=a') 
Modifiers=a means "needs authentication"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can not force authentication on port SMTP (25) if you want to receive messages from "strangers" (other SMTP hosts *worldwide*).

You should require authentication on SMTPS (465) and MSA (587) ports.

You may reject connection from [DUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialup_Users_List) (dynamically allocated) IP addresses for unauthenticated connections and addresses listed by other [DNSBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsbl) lists. Use FEATURE(enhdnsbl,...) with some DNSBL listing DUL ranges and FEATURE(delay_checks,...).

---

BTW You have missed s Modifier for SMTPS.

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=SMTPS,Port=465,Modifiers=sa')
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wondered why smtp.gmx.net : 25 can have authentication.
What does modifier "s" mean? I only know a,b,v,f,h,C,E.

Comment: `M=s` means "automatically start SSL layer **before** even sending SMTP greeting (SMTPS). Incoming mail to gmx.net mailboxes is handled according to `MX` DNS records by `mx00.gmx.net` and  `mx01.gmx.net`. `smtp.gmx.net` is for email from gmx.net users to other domains.

Comment: OK, now the Server does not allow sending email unauthenticated over port 25, except when it gets mail from an external server (i used relay_based_on_MX, relay_mail_from and `delay_checks', `friend' as relay rules). Have I forgotten something?